# Exception processing async thread queue

Tags: android, java

При дебаге вылезает ошибка:

> Exception processing async thread queue java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Как лечить?

Comment: можно вопрос по конкретней?

Comment: При добавлении в интент вылетает экспшн       
intent.putExtra("GROUP", names.get(position));

Comment: > экспшн  

ну тпр збс пнтн

Comment: Приведите весь код, и весь Стактрейс. Сдается мне, что вы привели самую верхнюю ошибку... а настоящей причиной является какой ни будь нул поинтер, или аут оф баундс

Answer (score 6):

Гугл намекает: [Exception processing async thread queue java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184776/exception-processing-async-thread-queue-java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception).

А вообще вопрос ни о чем. Нам лишь остается включить фантазию, чтобы понять, в чем у вас проблема.

**upd** напомнило и улыбнуло:

варю пельмени, получается невкусно. что я делаю не так?
жена изменяет. почему?
машина не едет. в чем причина?